# node webpack sass SASS not showing in browser

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I'm trying to use sass to style an example project for an online course.  Everything compiles successfully but I'm not seeing any of the styles in the browser.

I have five files in my styles folder:

```
base.scss
footer.scss
form.scss
header.scss
resets.scss
```

When I run

```
npm run build-dev
```

everything compiles.  In my main.js file I do see this:

```
var ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___ = __webpack_require__(/*! ../../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js */ "./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js");
exports = ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___(false);
// Module
exports.push([module.i, "/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/\r\n    v2.0 | 20110126\r\n    License: none (public domain)\r\n*/\nhtml, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {\n  margin: 0;\n  padding: 0;\n  border: 0;\n  font-size: 100%;\n  font: inherit;\n  vertical-align: baseline; }\n\n/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */\narticle, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {\n  display: block; }\n\nbody {\n  line-height: 1; }\n\nol, ul {\n  list-style: none; }\n\nblockquote, q {\n  quotes: none; }\n  blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {\n    content: '';\n    content: none; }\n\ntable {\n  border-collapse: collapse;\n  border-spacing: 0; }\n", ""]);
// Exports
module.exports = exports;
```

so i see resets.scss in main.js but I don't see any styles in my browser.  This is my config file:

webpack.dev.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/client/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    stats: 'verbose',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: '/\.js$/',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/client/views/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html",
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            // Simulate the removal of files
            dry: true,
            // Write Logs to Console
            verbose: true,
            // Automatically remove all unused webpack assets on rebuild
            cleanStaleWebpackAssets: true,
            protectWebpackAssets: false
        })
    ]
}
```

This is my client index.js file:

```
import { checkForName } from './js/nameChecker';
import { handleSubmit } from './js/formHandler';
import './styles/resets.scss';


console.log(checkForName);

alert("I EXIST")
console.log("CHANGE!!");
```

and this is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/resets.scss">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/base.scss">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/header.scss">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/form.scss">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/footer.scss">
    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <div class="">
                Logo
            </div>
            <div class="">
                navigation
            </div>
        </header>

        <main>
            <section>
                <form class="" onsubmit="return handleSubmit(event)">
                    <input id="name" type="text" name="input" value="" onblur="onBlur()" placeholder="Name">
                    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit" onclick="return handleSubmit(event)" onsubmit="return handleSubmit(event)">
                </form>
            <section>

            <section>
                <strong>Form Results:</strong>
                <div id="results"></div>
            </section>
        </main>

        <footer>
            <p>This is a footer</p>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried naming the .scss .css instead.  I have also tried calling the css with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../dist/main.js"></script>
```

instead of each individual file.  This is my resets.scss file:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;

    &:before, &:after {
        content: '';
        content: none;
    }
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

and this is one of my other css files for example:

header.scss:

```
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 40px;
}
```

Why am I not seeing the header show up as a flexbox?

Any help would be much appreciated.  index.html and the css files were provided by the lesson and sometimes the provided code is incomplete.  Is that the issue here?  Are the files not compiling correctly?

Thanks alot,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I wasn't importing the scss files in index.js:

```
import { checkForName } from './js/nameChecker';
import { handleSubmit } from './js/formHandler';
import './styles/resets.scss';
import './styles/base.scss'
import './styles/form.scss'
import './styles/footer.scss'
import './styles/header.scss'


console.log(checkForName);

alert("I EXIST")
console.log("CHANGE!!");
```